# Rails append parameter to URL based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application and on the index page I have a dropdown to select number of records displayed on the page, along with this I also have a search form to filter the result set.

I want to append the dropdown selection to the URL

e.g. when I search records, the url becomes `?utf8=✓&search=as&button=` but now when the user change the number of records displayed to `per_page=10` (10 is the user selection from the dropdown) the url should become `?utf8=✓&search=as&button=&per_page=10`

I tried following code, but with every user selections, the per_page keeps adding to the url, my code line is

```
<%= select_tag :per_page, 
               options_for_select([10,20,30], 
               params[:per_page].to_i), 
               :onchange => "if(this.value){window.location+='&per_page='+this.value;}" %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding to the url? 20+30+10.. each time user selects a value form drop-down?

Comment: @learner  1st time the user selects 10, the url is `?utf8=✓&search=as&button=&per_page=10`, now user selects 20, the url is now `?utf8=✓&search=as&button=&per_page=10&per_page=20` and like wise.

Comment: In this code `if(this.value){window.location+='&per.....`, is "+" sign required before "=" sign? I suspect that's causing the problem for you. Try `if(this.value){window.location='&per....`.

Comment: @learner if I use, `if(this.value){window.location='&per._page...`, then my search parameters from the url is gone which I dont want. (changes from `http://localhost:3000/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=as&button=` to `http://localhost:3000/orders?per_page=6`

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue since I've to configure my routes and index page. If you provide additional code, I can try in my system. Meanwhile have you tried =+'&per.....'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to wrap the select into a form tag and submit the form in `onchange` handler. It can look something like the following (I assume that you have `orders_path` route available and want to keep `params[:search]` value):

```
<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => "get" do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= select_tag :per_page, options_for_select([10,20,30], params[:per_page].to_i), :onchange => "this.form.submit()" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried with the form_tag, but now when I submit the form, the search params are gone. I want to keep the form result limited to the search results.

Comment: You can add `hidden_field_tag` elements to the form to keep the search params. I updated the example.